# show data with reading column name for json

Tags: php

I always show my data look like bellow for printing JSON .

Current Code:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($data) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {    
        $info[] = array(
            'ID' =>"".$row['id'],
            'game_id' =>"".$row['game_id'],
            'appliance_name'=>"".$row['appliance_name'],
            'area'=>"".$row['area'],                        
            'type' =>"".$row['type'],
            'description'=>"".$row['description'],
            'code'=>"".$row['code']                         
        );
    }
}
```

Here i want to show my array key name as database table column name as a example

when my query face data and store it in $info array that time automatically name of key make will be column name `code'=>` then the value.

So I have no tension how many column exist in database and what will be every array key name

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $info[] =$row;

}
```

working code.